# Nonstandard extension linking error using CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion

I have a [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) project for which I have a [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) that builds perfectly with GCC.

I wanted to play around with non-standard extensions and changed (using *mv*) a single *Manager.cpp* file to *Manager.cu*. I am trying to compile the project with GCC.

The following marked within ** are the modifications made

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 **-xc++**")
set(SOURCE_FILES
        **Manager.cu**
            .......
            .......
)
**set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)**
**add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})**
**set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)**
```

When I try to build this in CLion 2018.2, I see that it is built successfully because of the following message:

> [  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/medyan/src/Manager.cu.o 
> ...

Upon building all files, in the linking stage, I get infinite errors and warnings of the following type

```
...*.cpp.o error: stray ‘\371’ in program ..*cpp.o: error: stray ‘\34’
in program ....*.cu.o: error: stray ‘\2’ in program ....*.cu.o:
warning: null character(s) ignored ..*.cpp.o:3209:629: warning: null
character(s) ignored ..*.cpp.o:3209:1: error: stray ‘\22’ in program
..*.cpp.o:3209:631: warning: null character(s) ignored
..*.cpp.o:3209:1: error: stray ‘\24’ in program
```

I am not able to debug this as the error message is not helpful. Does it mean that CMake did not build it properly in the first place? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: There's probably some stray utf-8 bytes in your cpp file. It can happen when hitting weird keyboard combos accidentally. Check git diff or rewrite the offending characters

Comment: But will it cascade to all files in the project? I have merely changed extension of a single file but the stray character errors are all across the project.

Comment: Check VERBOSE=1 to see if the compiler is invoked correctly

Comment: You made a lot of extra changes for simply compiling `Manager.cu` as C++.  You probably don't need to set `LINKER_LANGUAGE` if this is an existing C++ project.  It seems redundant to add `-xc++` and set the `LANGUAGE` property.  One or the other should be sufficient.  Is the linker error literally stating `*.cpp.o` or did you edit the error?

Comment: @Fred With just -xc++ alone, building results in failure to compile .cu files. So I get linker errors.
With just set_source_files_properties, .cu files are also compiled but I get the error "linker input file unused because linking not done."
I had to use both to get it right.
And no I do not get "*.cu" * was just used to refer to filenames. The file names listed during the stray character error were all files in the project.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going on.

1. `set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)` is needed to make sure that the source files are added into the project.  In `MSYS Makefiles` generator any unrecognized files are not candidates for being compiled.  In `Visual Studio` it just shows up in the IDE as a text file.
2. In generators like `MSYS Makefiles` it doesn't automatically add the proper compiler flag to compile a file with a non-standard extension.  In contrast the `Visual Studio` generator does know how to do this and no extra steps are necessary.
3. Adding the `-xc++` flag this way `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -xc++)` breaks things.  That's because these flags are also used during the `link` process.  So on the link line it'll tell `g++` to treat all object and archive files as `c++` files and `compile` them.
4. `add_definitions("-xc++")` works around these issues because it adds the flag on the `compile` line not `link` line.

Don't use `add_definitions("-xc++")`, use `set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILES} PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS -xc++)` instead.  Why? Because the first way makes every single file used in any target in `CMakeLists.txt` a `c++` file which can cause problems if `c` files are used elsewhere.  The second way just adds the `-xc++` option just to the files in `${SOURCE_FILES}`.

Answer (score 1):

So the key change was to add "-xc++" as a definition and not as part of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS i.e.

```
add_definitions("-xc++")
```

This prevents the strange errors I was receiving and it compiles, and links effectively with no errors.